# Multicolumn index with expression (PostgreSQL and Rails)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to create multicolumn index for 3 columns (`VARCHAR`, `INT` and `INT`), lets call them `varchar_col`, `int1_col` and `int2_col`. For `VARCHAR` column I need to apply `lower(varchar_col)` expression.

When I create one-column index with expression

```
add_index :table, 'lower(varchar_col)', name: 'index_name'
```

it works, but when I try to create multicolumn with

```
add_index :table, ['lower(varchar_col)', :int1_col, :int2_col], name: 'index_name'
```

I receive

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "lower(varchar_col)" does not exist

Is it possible to create such an index with Rails `add_index` function or I need to execute SQL query in migration file? Does PostgreSQL support multicolumn index with expression? And if it supports, what I have to write in migration file to make it works?

Thank you for any help!

P.S. I'm using Rails 5.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may send the columns with the expressions as a string:

```
add_index :table, 'lower(varchar_col), int1_col, int2_col', name: 'index_name'
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Though I've already made it with executing SQL query in migration file ;) I added answer with it below.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a little research, I've made it with executing SQL query in migration file. I just leave it here as another approach, but Ilya Lavrov's suggestion with string of columns also works.

**migration file**:

```
def up
  connection.execute(%q{
    CREATE INDEX index_name ON table(lower(varchar_col), int1_col, int2_col)
  })
end

def down
  remove_index :table, name: 'index_name'
end
```